# sd card ejects after formating as internal via google files app

Tags: adb, external-sd, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, formatting

I am trying to increase the internal storage of my realme narzo 30a phone. but it doesnt support format as internal. so i enabled usb debugging and used `sm set-force-adoptabe true` via `adb`. Then i formatted it as internal storage from google files app. as soon as i press done, i get a popup saying sd card is ejected. I also tried mounting via adb using`sm mount private DISK;VOLUME`
but i got an error saying its inaccessible...

If I dont press done after formatting using files, it doesnt seem to get ejected, but it is not shown in storge...

is there no way to use sd card as internal storage?

what is funny to me is that it works just fine on a moto e40 i tried it in... even the speeds were not bad.

Comment: How old is the used sd-card and have it been used before? Some sd-cards claim to have a higher capacity that they have flash memory inside. Such cards act totally weird if they reach the internal limit. If the card is new I would recommend to perform a flash capacity test using a PC before using it in Android.

Comment: @Robert It seems to have been a problem with realme devices, apparently workarounds don't work. my sd card was a 128gb samsung one and it's legit. i ended up having to reset my phone after installing TaiChi to move CoD's obb to the sd card lol... not worth it imo

do you know anything about xposed or TaiChi just crashing when packaging the app? my storage got eaten up every time and was not listed, hence had to reset my phone.